# Adding background Image in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uikit, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to add an image in the background of UINavigationBar. There is no direct option through interface builder but I have seen apps implemented this thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UIView` and add it as a subview.

Edit: You can now use [`setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationBar/setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:). Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765102/313875

Comment: Updated to reflect the fact that this is no longer the way of doing it.

Comment: Great to see someone keeping their answers up to date. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"strip.png"];
        [upnavbar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

this wil work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your background as a subview, as jrtc27 suggested and change the tint color according your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the drawRect function.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCustom)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_logo.png"];
    [image drawInRect:rect];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the *drawLayer:inContext:* method in a UINavigationBar category class. Inside the *drawLayer:inContext:* method, you can draw the background image you want to use. You can also use different sized images for portrait and landscape orientations if you'd like to.

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]] == NO) {
        return;
    }

    UIImage *image = (self.frame.size.width > 320) ?
                        [UINavigationBar bgImageLandscape] : [UINavigationBar bgImagePortrait];
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
}
```

And as a complete demo Xcode project on customizing the appearance of UINavigationBar [this](http://www.ardalahmet.com/2011/02/11/ios-development/customizing-the-appearance-of-uinavigationbar/) and [this](https://github.com/ardalahmet/CustomizingNavigationBarBackground) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an article about customization of background for UINavigatioBar and UIToolbar. You can find a code sample and categories for seamless integration of this functionality in your app by following link — http://leonov.co/2011/04/uinavigationbar-and-uitoolbar-customization-ultimate-solution/