# How do I add an image to the Navigation bar as a background?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Can anyone explain how to add an image as your navigation bar's background in swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the UINavigationBar background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764309/changing-the-uinavigationbar-background-image)

Comment: As this is fundamentally the same question as the Obj-C equivalent, I've updated the referenced question and voted for this one to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColinE answer is correct, is just that your navigation bar isn't called `myNavbar`.

You can try using:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "logo.png"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

inside the `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you, and Colin.

Answer (score 1):

See this question for the answer in Objective-C:

[Changing the UINavigationBar background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764309/changing-the-uinavigationbar-background-image)

Which translates to:

```
myNavbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "logo.png"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: Does this work for a standard NavBar View Controller? I tried your code and it came back that myNavbar is an unresolved identifier. Thank you.